# Qubit can't be copied

Tags: quantum-information

I am a beginner in a Quantum Cryptography course, it is little bit confusing to think about how the theory describes practical situations.

The statement

> A qubit state can't be copied

is proven in this way: first, they discuss what copying a qubit means. I am facing a problem in this step. Then, they assume there exists such *unitary* transformation and arrive a a contradiction by applying this transformation on the Hadamard basis.

In my notes (Caltech) it is written that copying qubit means there is an *unitary* operation that does the following: 
           $$U\left|\Psi\right>_A\left|0\right>_B=\left|\Psi\right>_A\left|\Psi\right>_B$$
I do not understand this fully. Can anyone explain how this expression describes copying a qubit? In brief: Can anyone explain what is the physical meaning of the *tensor product* of two states?

Comment: More on the [no-cloning theorem](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+no+cloning+theorem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we have two distinguishable quantum systems $A$ and $B$, then the Hilbert space for describing the dynamics of both systems considered as one system is the tensor product $\mathcal{H}_2 = \mathcal{H}_A \otimes \mathcal{H}_B$ of the Hilbert spaces (in other words the space that is *spanned* by the tensor products of elements taken from the two spaces or equivalently taken from the bases of the two spaces). Operators acting in one of the spaces $\mathcal{H}_A$ or $\mathcal{H}_B$ are mapped to the operator $O_A \otimes 1_B$ resp. $1 \otimes O_B$ in $\mathcal{H}_2$. Operators acting on both systems at the same time (interactions) are of the form $O_A \otimes O_B$ or a sum of such terms.

Now the interpretation is, that the state $\left|\Psi\right>_A \left|0\right>_B$ describes the state of a system consisting of two distinguishable quantum objects (let's say two qubits) where, when we consider the parts isolated the object $A$ is in state $\left|\Psi\right>$ and the object $B$ is in state $\left|0\right>$.

This description of systems consisting of parts is natural can be made plausible by considering its consequences:

- If we have two systems and want to get the state of the composite system, the norm of the composite wave function must be one. This is fulfilled by the tensor product (which I write as $\otimes$ in the following for clarity): $$ \left(\left< \Psi \right| \otimes \left<\Phi\right| \right)\left(\left|\Psi\right> \otimes \left|\Phi\right>\right) = \left<\Psi\middle|\Psi\right> \left<\Phi\middle|\Phi\right> = 1. $$
- The action of an operator acting on one of the systems must be independent of the state of the other part of the system. This is encoded by the mapping $O_A \mapsto O_A \otimes 1$, consider the expectation value $$\left(\left<\Psi\right| \otimes \left<\Phi\right|\right)(O_A \otimes 1) \left(\left|\Psi\right> \otimes \left|\Phi\right>\right) = \left<\Psi \middle| O_A \middle| \Psi \right> \left<\Phi \middle| 1 \middle| \Phi\right> = \left<\Psi \middle| O_A \middle| \Psi \right>. $$
- Operators describing interactions are naturally available.

---

Finally, we can explain why the operator of the form given above is the operator for copying a qubit state: Starting from a state where the qubit $A$ is in an arbitrary state $\left|\Psi\right>$ and the other is in some known state $\left|0\right>$ we end up in a state $\left|\Psi\right>_A \left|\Psi\right>_B$ where both qubits are in state $\left|\Psi\right>$, which means we have copied the state of qubit $A$ to qubit $B$.